# checkBox checked not working

Tags: android, android-intent, checkbox

i'm having some trouble working with there checkbox. So in my app the user as 2 check boxes, and then a button, that button opens a new intent, and i need to pass the information through the intent to know if the checkbox is checked or not. I'm passing that information with the .putExtra() but then in the new intent when i do a if statement my app always crashes here because it gives me always a null pointer exception.
Here's the code for the button and pass the information:

```
final CheckBox sabado = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSabado);
    final CheckBox domingo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDomingo);

    //Clique no botao "PROCURAR"
    buttonProcurar.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(deTextPartida.getText().toString().equals(paraTextDestino.getText().toString())){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Partida e destino nao podem ser iguais, escolha de novo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Intent i = new Intent(horariosMenu.this, mostraHorario.class);
                        i.putExtra("Partida", deTextPartida.getText().toString());
                        i.putExtra("Destino", paraTextDestino.getText().toString());
                        i.putExtra("Sabado", sabado.isChecked());
                        i.putExtra("Domingo", domingo.isChecked());
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

And here's the code to get it:

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(data == null){
        return;
    }
    String Partida = data.getString("Partida");
    String Destino = data.getString("Destino");
    String Sabado = data.getString("Sabado");
    String Domingo = data.getString("Domingo");

    if(Sabado.equals("true")){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Sabado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

What am i doing wrong guys ? :X

Comment: you are puttin a boolean, you are reading a string.

Comment: When i do data.getString("Sabado") the result isn't suppose to be "true" ?

Comment: Since you didn't put a string in it, no, it's not supposed to return anything. Didn't you try to see what was the value in there?

Comment: I tried just to make the toast with the string Sabado in there, to see what was it. Like :
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Sabado, Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
But the result was just a small black square, didn't get it :x

Comment: Post the exception log here. When was the exception occured? In this code `String Sabado = data.getString("Sabado");` or in this code `i.putExtra("Sabado", sabado.isChecked());`?

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer posted is wrong. The bundle which i.getExtras() return can get these vars too. And in my experiment your code get nothing wrong. Do you check you add another activity to your manifest file?

Comment: I managed to correct with ur previous answer, its working now. Just made a few changes. in the getBooleanExtra() i add "true", so it was getBooleanExtra("Sabado", true") , and then instead of Sabado.equals("true") i just had to put if(Sabado), since its a boolean, works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ended up solving my problem. I'll post here so if in the future there are some with the same problem they can check right here.
I just changed my bundle, i found a way to get the Extras information another way :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Partida = intent.getStringExtra("Partida");
    String Destino = intent.getStringExtra("Destino");
    boolean Sabado = intent.getBooleanExtra("Sabado", true);
    boolean Domingo = intent.getBooleanExtra("Domingo", true);
```

And in the if statement (the one causing problem) i just had to do:

```
if(Sabado){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Sabado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Because now "Sabado" is a boolean, and so in if(Sabado) i check if he is true or false, wich is the value of if the checkbox is checked or not. 
So that's it guys, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In "sabado" y "domingo" you are sending boolean values through putExtra method. Then in the Activity that receive the data, you assign a String value. You can write some like:

```
i.putExtra("Sabado", sabado.isChecked()+"");
i.putExtra("Domingo", domingo.isChecked()+"");
```

And then:

```
String Sabado = data.getString("Sabado");
String Domingo = data.getString("Domingo");
```